# JavaScript breaks without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, alert, kineticjs

Having a JavaScript problem, can't figure out why the code works when including the alert after the onload function, and why it doesn't work when the alert is removed.

```
var jsonObjects = [];
var imagesObj = {};
var kinImages = [];
var stage;
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

window.onload = function () {
    var jsonloaded;
    $.getJSON('net.json', function (response) {
        jsonloaded = response;
        $.each(jsonloaded, function (key, val) {
            jsonObjects.push(val);
        });
        setupJsonImages();
    });
}

function setupJsonImages() {
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 1000,
        height: 800
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length; i++) {
        var objName = jsonObjects[i].name;
        imagesObj[objName] = new Image();
        kinImages[i] = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: imagesObj[objName],
            x: jsonObjects[i].x,
            y: jsonObjects[i].y,
            name: jsonObjects[i].name,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            draggable: true
        });
        imagesObj[objName].src = jsonObjects[i].img;
        imagesObj[objName].onload = function () {
            layer.add(kinImages[i]);
            layer.draw();
        }
        // if this alert is removed, the code breaks
        alert("imagesobj src");
        kinImages[i].on('dragend', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'receiver.php',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                async: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    objectname: (this).getName(),
                    xcoord: (this).getPosition().x,
                    ycoord: (this).getPosition().y
                })
            });
        });
    }
    stage.add(layer);
    stage.draw();
}
```

Have read something about Ajax and asynchronous code and that the alert creates a delay, but that doesn't make sense since the ajax code is only called after dragend?

Comment: What's your thought behind `async: false`?

Comment: @Johan I have no thought about it, it's from Kineticjs example code. It works the same with either true or false.

Comment: alert is giving time for the `imagesObj[objName].onload` to finish. You could use promises and resolve them before calling `stage.add() ` and `stage.draw()`

Comment: "It works the same with either true or false.". No, a synchronous call is, well, synchronous. It freezes the thread until it's complete.

Comment: @Johan yes of course, but the result of the original code still ends up the same, it won't work if the alert is not there.

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, i'll give it a go. Might be better off to rewrite most of it either way, using someone elses example is obviously not the best solution :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a rewrite and got the result I was after. Works fairly well so far :-)

```
var jsonObjects = [];
var imagesObj = {};
var kinImages = [];
var stage;
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

window.onload = function() {

  $.getJSON('net.json', function(response){
    $.each( response, function( key, val ) {
      jsonObjects.push( val );
    });
    createStage();
  });
}

function createStage() {

  stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 1000,
    height: 800
  });
  setupJsonImages(-1);
}

function setupJsonImages(index) {

  index++;
  var objName = jsonObjects[index].name;
  imagesObj[objName] = new Image();
  imagesObj[objName].src = jsonObjects[index].img;

  imagesObj[objName].onload = function() {

    setupKinetic(index, imagesObj[objName]);
  }
}

function setupKinetic(index, theImage) {

  kinImages[index] = new Kinetic.Image({
    image: theImage,
    x: jsonObjects[index].x,    // 0,
    y: jsonObjects[index].y,   //0
    name: jsonObjects[index].name,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    draggable: true
  });

  layer.add(kinImages[index]);
  layer.draw();

  kinImages[index].on('dragend',function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'receiver.php',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      async: true,
      data: JSON.stringify({ 
        objectname:(this).getName(), 
        xcoord: (this).getPosition().x, 
        ycoord : (this).getPosition().y 
      })
    });
  });

  if(index < jsonObjects.length -1) {
    setupJsonImages(index);
  }
  else {
    finishStage();
  }
}

function finishStage() {

  stage.add(layer);
  stage.draw();
}
```

Probably not the most elegant solution code-wise, but it works and fills the need atm.
Appreciate the input from all posters.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
window.onload = function() {  

    $.getJSON('net.json', function(){ 
        console.log('it worked');
    }).done(function(response){
        $.each( response, function( key, val ) {
            jsonObjects.push( val );
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why would you use the shorthand success callback *and* `done`? One of them is enough.

Comment: @Red2678 it doesn't change anything to use this.

Comment: @Johan just trying to delay it a bit. Why don't you post and answer if you have a better one? I see a lot of your comments, but no answer ;) @ Poppe76 sry!

Comment: @Red2678 Thanks, have read the api, and it hasn't helped much...  have read 5-6 threads in here about alert "fixing" the code, but none that have helped me. Am thinking about rewriting.. can't be that hard to write a loop that only steps after onload is finished :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the `setupJsonImages` function this code adds the images to the layer:

```
imagesObj[objName].onload = function() {
  layer.add(kinImages[i]);
  layer.draw();
}
```

In this code, the value of `i` will typically be `jsonObjects.length` since `i` is scoped to the `setupJsonImages` function and by the time onload executes the for loop has finished.  The alert statement pins the `i` val at the current value because of the stoppage which makes it work.

Try replacing your for loop with this:

```
for( var i=0; i<jsonObjects.length; i++) {
    var objName = jsonObjects[i].name;
    imagesObj[objName] = new Image();
    imagesObj[objName].src = jsonObjects[i].img;
    // hook up the data we need in the onload event
    var $imgObj = $(imagesObj[objName]);
    $imgObj.data({
        x: jsonObjects[i].x,
        y: jsonObjects[i].y,
        name: jsonObjects[i].name
    });
    imagesObj[objName].onload = function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var kinImg = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: this, // this = the loaded image
            x: $this.data('x'),
            y: $this.data('y'),
            name: $this.data('name'),
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            draggable: true
        });

        kinImg.on('dragend',function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'receiver.php',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                async: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({ objectname:(this).getName(), xcoord: (this).getPosition().x, ycoord : (this).getPosition().y })
            });
        });
        kinImages.push(kinImg);
        layer.add(kinImages);
        layer.draw();
    };
}
```

Comment: can't get that to work, the images won't load at all.
The onload function runs as many times as expect, but the images doesn't load. And if i put an alert after layer.draw() it doesn't show up. A syntax miss somewhere perhaps? May end up rewriting the whole thing with jQuery and skip kinetcjs altogether...

Comment: try removing the `layer.draw()`